# change a commands name in a linux system

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a Linux system, I want to change the names of the commands in the system through the kernal, for example, **ls to show** or **cd to enter**, how do I do that.

I searched on the Internet on how to change the names of the commands, but I did not find an explanation for this matter. Who has an excellent source to give it to me?

Comment: You can use alias, functions or symlinks (which point to the command you want to *rename*).

Answer (score 5):

The kernel doesn’t care what names commands have; commands’ names are decided by the file names of binaries which implement them, and for shell-internal commands such as `cd`, by the shell which provides them.

In fact, your shell most likely provides mechanisms by which you can give new names to commands for your own use, without breaking the expectations of other programs which may rely on them. Typically,

```
alias show=ls
alias enter=cd
```

will create the two commands you’ve given as examples.

Comment: Thank you, Mister.Stephen Kitt 
Do you have a source that explains how to change command names from in a files?

Comment: @MohammedAnwarAlhamed If you're trying to rename the actual command, don't do that.  [Quite a few utilities/commands have standard names](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/idx/utilities.html), and changing them will break anything that depends on the utility being usable with its standard name, like `ls` or `cd`.  Things like the startup scripts that run when your system boots up, for example.  Run `find /etc/rc?.d/` - every one of the files listed is a script that relies on standard utilities existing and behaving as expected.  Or `file /bin/* | grep script`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a bash script to automate creating multiple aliases.

Bash scripting is not hard to learn the basics, but it is too much to  explain here. However, there are lots of good tutorials on bash scripting available online.